# An ordering different from the Gray order (digits change by 1 at each step)

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

Given $A=\lbrace x_n,\ldots x_1\rbrace$. How would I construct an ordering on the subsets of $A$ such that the immediate successor of a subset is obtained by either adding or deleting one element, and the order is not a reflected Gray code, no matter how you re-index the elements of $A$?

Would this work for $n=3$?
$\emptyset; \lbrace x_1\rbrace,\lbrace x_1,x_2\rbrace,A, \lbrace x_2,x_3 \rbrace \lbrace x_2\rbrace, \lbrace x_1, x_3\rbrace, \lbrace x_3\rbrace $?
Does this idea of adding elements until I reach $A$, removing elements until I get back to singleton, increasing as much as I can after that, then decreasing work for larger $n$?

**EDIT**
The reflected Gray code is defied inductively by

(1) the reflected Gray code of order $1$ is $0;1$.

(2) Suppose $n>1$ and the reflected Gray code of order $n-1$ has been constructed. To construct the reflected Gray code of order $n$, we first list the $(n-1)$-tuples of 0s and 1s in the order given by the reflected Gray code or order $n-1$, and attach a $0$ at the beginning (i.e. on the left) of each $(n-1)$-tuple. We then list the $(n-1)-$tuples in the order which is the reverse given by the reflected Gray code of order $n-1$, and attach a $1$ at the beginning.

Comment: So you are looking for a Gray code that is not (a permuted version of) the most common (=reflected?) Gray code? Will any of the constructions listed in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) fit the bill?

Comment: I'll check those out. The idea is that for n=k, we can consider the Gray order as a path along the edges of a hyper k-cube.  If n=3, the  Gray order exhausts all corners of one face of the cube, then it glides across the top edge and exhausts all of the corners on the other face. My goal is to glide back and forth so that there will be no Gray order, no matter how the corners are indexed (since glides distinguish between the number of elements in a subset of $A$).

Comment: This has to be the way to go since if we keep our path on the same edges as long as the Gray order does, we can break this ordering by reindexing (such that the reindexing gives a Gray order)

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing is **the** Gray order. You are apparently thinking about the binary reflected Gray code. While that is commonly described in textbooks, I think that all the orderings with the Gray property are called Gray codes.

Comment: Ah. I'm referring to "the Gray order" referred to in Brualdi's Intro to Combinatorics Text. I'll edit he above to add this in.

Comment: By the way, Gray codes have a neat practical application: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder. The 'Standard binary encoding' section in that article describes the problem and the 'Gray encoding' section describes how Gray codes fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A_n = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$.

As Jyrki pointed out in the comments, your book's definition of a Gray code is actually a special case: the binary reflected Gray code. This construction always puts $00\cdots0$ at the start of the code and $10\cdots0$ at the end. If you cycle all elements of the code forward one position, you'll get something that isn't a binary reflected Gray code, but still has distance $1$ between subsequent codewords.

For example, the binary reflected Gray code of length 3 is $000,001,011,010,110,111,101,100$. Cycle those ahead one position to get $\underline{100},000,001,011,010,110,111,101$. Now use the usual bijection between length $n$ binary strings and subsets of a size $n$ set to get the order

$$
\{x_1\}; \emptyset; \{x_3\}; \{x_2,x_3\}; \{x_2\}; \{x_1,x_2\}; A_3; \{x_1,x_3\}.
$$

Comment: How do I know that we can't reindex the elements so that this will be in the reflected Gray order?

Comment: Try it with the $n=3$ example I gave: no matter what index you put instead of $x_1$, it'll still have one element, so the corresponding binary string will have one $1$ in it, so it won't be a Gray code (since they always start with $00\cdots0$).

Comment: Yeah, something like that: http://i.imgur.com/18wj5eL.jpg (Oops, you deleted your comment before I posted. I'll leave the picture up, though.)

Comment: That is the picture. Thank you.